# Reload Google Ad iFrame when separate photo gallery iframe is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, google-dfp

I have thouroughly researched this and spent 2 days trying to get it going. Apparently a previous dev was able to refresh an Google Ad (with GPT tags) in an iframe to reload and load a different ad whenever the user clicked every 3rd slide on a photo gallery which sits in a separate iframe on the page.

I have never seen this working, however the existing code he had does make the other iframe refresh but the next doesn't doesn't load, the iframe body is empty. the ad iframe has an ID of "companion", he was using

```
top.$("#companion IFRAME").attr("src", top.$("#companion IFRAME").attr("src"));
```

I have tried several other methods using JS and jQuery to try and do this, such as:

```
var iframe = top.$("#companion IFRAME");
iframe.src = iframe.src;
```

or
    top.$("#companion IFRAME").attr( 'src', function ( i, val ) { return val; });
and others, also tried with just "companion" as the ID

the Google GPT tags also allow a method to automatically refresh the ads using for example:

```
slot1 = googletag.defineSlot('/39761691/[var ADTAGGING_SITE]_[var ADTAGGING_DARTZONE]', [300, 250], 'companion').addService(googletag.pubads()).setTargeting('pos', '1');

googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);
```

I successfully have this working using the timed function they suggested, so reloads it every 10 seconds. But was unable to incorporate this Google scripting into my photgallery script. Couldn't define the googletag variables.

I know Javascript and a bit of jQuery, however I am no expert and may be missing something fundamentally wrong, however judging by the errors in the console I assumed it is the same origin policy getting in the way cos they're on my domain and the google domain.

Here is one of the pages I am talking about, ad is to the right of the photo gallery:
http://chm.live7.mediaspanonline.com/photos/artist-profile-led-zeppelin

Is there a way to do this? Please help! Thank you

John

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have a lot of time to dig, but off the top of my head, have you tried `top.googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);` or `parent.googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);` from within that iframe?

Essentially, you just want to run the function `googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);`, but that function exists on the parent.

Comment: Hi, do you mean within the photogallery_v4.js file itself under the same function or somewhere else? Sorry could you please clarify a bit further?

I tried both of those lines there but nothing refreshed

Comment: Correct - you should be able to add `top.googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);` where you have `top.location.hash = $(this).attr("slugline");` in that file.

Comment: Actually - you can't define the adSlot as a `var` because it's only available to that function/script, so you'll need to name it something unique and remove the `var`.

Comment: Im facing same issue. Can you suggest me how you solve this?